# Why do most programming languages not respect the executable flag on a file?

Tags: python, linux, executable

Why do most programming languages (Python, Bash, etc) not respect the executable flag on programs?

E.g. if I have a Python script that doesn't have the executable flag enabled, running that program in the shell directly yields an error, yet running it with Python does not:

```
$ ./test.py
bash: ./test.py: Permission denied
$ python3 test.py
... program output ...
```

Why is the `+x` flag ignored so often?

Does the lack of an `x` flag not denote that a file should not be run/executed/interpreted?

Comment: It is not just python. You will get the same behaviour with any other interpreted language. You would see the same thing with bash for example.

Comment: I know. Why is this the case? I thought part of the point of the flag was as a protective feature and that the intended behavior was that if `+x` was not set, the file should not be treated as code that could be run/executed/interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

Python is simply interpreting the file, not executing it.

The only thing being *executed* here is `python` itself.

---

#### EDIT

The important thing to understand is that in the case of bash, it will actually *execute* the program you give it by either looking for a shebang line or simply fork a new process for the program and wait until the forked child is finished. This is why it throws an error if the `executable` bit is not set.

In the case of python, python is not executing anything, it automatically assumes the file is a python script, and then it *interprets* it. Therefore, python does not care if your script is executable or not, the only bit it cares about is if the file is actually a file and is *readable*.

Comment: Actually same thing happens with bash. You can give a file as parameter. `bash my_file.sh` and it will interpret that file like python does.

Answer (score 2):

Let look at `$ python3 test.py`, I believe `python3` is executable, `test.py` is a parameter pass to `python3` and `python3` find the file `test.py` under the same folder, the `test.py` has `+r` permission to let `python3` read the content.

Comment: I understand that `test.py` is the argument here. My question is why does Python not have code (like Bash does) that checks the `+x` flag and refuses to interpret the file without it?

Comment: @Zaz - it's NOT bash checking that. See my answer below.  It's the kernel. If you have a shell script without a shebang line you get the same issue.

Comment: My mistake. Why do Python and Bash and all these other programming languages not have code (like the kernel does) that checks the `+x` flag?

Comment: Because they're not *running* at the time.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do most programming languages (Python, Bash, etc) not respect the executable flag on programs?

[...]

> Does the lack of an x flag not denote that a file should not be run/executed/interpreted?

Correct: executable permission does not have the broad meaning you are trying to attribute to it.  As far as the system is concerned, execute permission on a given file for a given user means only that the system will allow that user to attempt to execute that file *as a command*.  It has no bearing on the behavior of programs (such as shells and language interpreters) that read the file as data.

To be sure, it would be possible for shells and the like to implement a parallel restriction themselves, but there's not much point to that.  If a user can read the file then they can make their own copy of it and assign whatever permissions they want, so as to enable them to run that copy.  Instead, shells and such tend to take a more user-friendly approach: they attempt to do what is asked of them, inasmuch as they can do.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a slight misconception here about how **stuff** on Linux gets executed.

Anything typed in a shell will be handed to the kernel after the <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

If it's an elf-executable it will be run directly.

If it has a *shebang* line the kernel will (try to) use whatever follows the `!#` as an interpreter to execute the rest of the file.

If it's not an executable and doesn't have a shebang line you get the error you're seeing, despite the executable flag.

The canonical solution to your problem is to prepend your python code in your script with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: *"If it's not an executable and doesn't have a shebang line you get the error you're seeing, despite the executable flag."* I think there is something wrong here. Your last words contradicts with the beginning. And even if was a typo error, what you are saying is not correct. Shebang line is not a hard requirement and you can execute your files without it.